# scale_fill_identity does not fill anything

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I used the `scale_fill_identity` function already with some code of mine. Now - all of a sudden - when using it - it does not fill anything.

Here is an example:

```
# Create example data
data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(4, 5, 6), fill = c("red", "blue", "yellow"))

# Create the plot
ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill)) +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

This gives me this:

[image]

So no color. Any suggestions on where the problem could be?

[image]

Comment: `geom_point`'s default plotting character does not use the "fill" aesthetic, though if you set `pch = 21`, that plotting character (and several others available in R) will make use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could *color* your points using `scale_color_identity`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
# Create the plot
ggplot(data) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color = fill)) +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Please check [this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_identity.html) for more examples about using `scale_identity`.